# Can this motherboard fit into this case?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, case

I'm interested if **Asus ROG Maximus XI Extreme** can fit into **Corsair Obsidian 500D SE RGB** case? I've found that some guys had hard time fitting **Maximus XI Hero** edition, so I'm not sure if **Extreme** would fit...

If this question isn't for this site, please tell me where to post it then.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The de-facto standard configuration for motherboards nowadays is the [ATX specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Variants). This specification has many variants which rule motherboards' dimensions. In the case of the Asus ROG Maximus XI Extreme, it is an Extended ATX (EATX) board, which is 305 by 330 millimeters.

[According to the manufacturer](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Cases/Software-Control-and-Monitoring-Cases/Obsidian-Series-500D-RGB-SE-Premium-Mid-Tower-Case/p/CC-9011139-WW#tab-tech-specs), the Corsair Obsidian 500D SE RGB is compatible with Standard ATX motherboards. So it most likely won't be compatible with the Maximus XI Extreme.

So you have two options: Either opt for a smaller, Standard ATX-sized motherboard and keep the Obsidian 500D case, or look for a case capable of housing an EATX board. If you prefer the second option, here is Corsair's selection of EATX capable cases: [click me!](https://www.corsair.com/uk/en/Categories/Products/Cases/c/Cor_Products_Cases?q=%3Afeatured%3AcaseMotherboardSupport%3AE-ATX&text=&pageSize=#rotatingText)

Comment: I saw somewhere that it was E-ATX compatible and thus my concern. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @asobak - The motherboard compatibility is on the specifications page for the case. I am not entirely sure where you might have seen it supported EATX motherboards, but it wasn't for the [Obsidian 500D](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Cases/Software-Control-and-Monitoring-Cases/Obsidian-Series-500D-RGB-SE-Premium-Mid-Tower-Case/p/CC-9011139-WW#tab-overview) case.